# DataContext db = new DataContext() - as a global

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC 5 app with EF6 started using interfaces and Ninject and ran into problems.

I call multiple implementations to get a data and when saving it entities are disconnected and have problems with many to many and similar.

So I want to make my `DataContext db = new DataContext();` global so I just refer to it, not create new instance in every class.

Where do I declare it and how to call it?

Comment: This is not a good idea. If you are having problems with disconnected entities then you need to attach them to your data context before working with them. Your many to many problems should not be affected by having a global DataContext.

Comment: I don't have it, I don't now how to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All u need is repository pattern and Unit of work.
there is useful link about implementation 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I think this is it, but I need some time to digest and test. Will inform on effect.

Comment: EF already implement Unit Of Work and Repository pattern itself, you should avoid add unnecessary complexity to your project. Maybe you can create Services/Business classes http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47865/database-first-entity-framework-repository-service-unitofwork-pattern

Comment: I'm bit overwhelmed. I think my project is not big enough and that I would just complicate things even more. Thank you all for effort.

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT DO THAT.

At least because, due to caching, you will finish to have all the database in memory.

Your DbContext MUST have a scope as small as possible. Certainly not an application scope.

"Let the connection pool do his job".